# Azure function deployment giving strange error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloud, devops, cicd

I am trying to deploy a flask api from vscode to azure function but on deployment I get this error mentioning if you are application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw73C.png)]

I looked everywhere but found no solution regarding this. Please help!

Comment: Are you deploying your application using Azure Pipelines? or is it normal deployment from visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

- Try deploying your application via CLI:
- Open Terminal=> navigate to the root directory of your application, run the command `func azure functionapp publish <functionappname>`
- I created a simple flask app and deployed to Azure functions:

[image]

[image]

- Make sure your application is being deployed to the correct service according to its requirement (Azure App Service/ Azure Functions).